# Nunit 3.0 Tests not running in parallel in TeamCity

Tags: nunit, teamcity, parallel-testing, nunit-3.0

We have a suite of API tests that we have been running on Teamcity with MBunit. There are around 200 tests that are set to run 12 in parallel and they take about 7 minutes to run. Nunit recently released version 3 and supports fixture parallelism. This works for me locally and I have seen the tests run just as fast from within Visual Studios as they did in MBunit.

In TeamCity using the NUnit runner type the tests took over 3 hours to run. The first 20 test each took right around 90 seconds then the remainder took 15 minutes each and were not run in parallel.

The only change i made to the tests was switching from MBUnit to NUnit.

I have attached the teamcity NUnit build step config I am using [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUeuo.png)

Comment: Is there a command line in the logs that shows what command line parameters Teamcity passed into nunit to run your tests?

Comment: "C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit.org\nunit-console\nunit-console.exe" C:\BuildAgent\temp\buildTmp\q3AUY8NnxNuE2gzUANbaWYDr31RSZzLE.nunit --work=C:\BuildAgent\work\97e2dc30fe0ff3d4 --noresult --noheader --framework=net-4.0 --workers=12

Comment: That's odd since the name of the NUnit 3.0 console runner is nunit3-console.exe. Does TeamCity have it's own renamed copy?

Comment: The problem is team city looks for Nunit-console.exe if you use the nunit runner type, so I just renamed the 3.0 exe i installed on the build agent.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else running into this, it was a TeamCity bug. Update to the latest version and it will fix it. The version i upgraded to was 9.1.6